# How to print(message.data) on foreground at Flutter & Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm adding [Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#foreground-messages) function to my Android APP, and I can't get message.data at foreground snipped.

The example is

```dart
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
  print('Message data: ${message.data}');

  if (message.notification != null) {
    print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
  }
});
```

It should print first line `Got a message whilst in the foreground!...`,
But I get

```
D/FLTFireMsgReceiver( XXXX): broadcast received for message
W/com.XXXXXX.XXXXXX( XXXX): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(I)Z (greylist,test-api, reflection, allowed)
W/com.XXXXXX.XXXXXX( XXXX): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(ILjava/lang/String;)Z (greylist,test-api, reflection, allowed)
W/com.XXXXXX.XXXXXX( XXXX): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->get(I)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/com.XXXXXX.XXXXXX( XXXX): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->getName(I)Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/6011), it looks like it's a bug with the latest version of `firebase_messaging` and the current workaround is to add a line to get the token before you listen to the messages.

Update your code to this:

```dart
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken(); // Add this line
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
  print('Message data: ${message.data}');

  if (message.notification != null) {
    print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank for reply, now it worked.
And did you know how not to show this snipped?

```dart
W/com.XXXXXX.XXXXXX( XXXX): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(I)Z (greylist,test-api, reflection, allowed)
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) async {
      if (message.notification != null) {
      print(
          'Message contained a notification, with the following:\nTitle: ${message.notification?.title}\nBody: ${message.notification?.body}');
    }
    return;
  }).onData((data) {
    print('Got a DATA message whilst in the FOREGROUND!');
    print('data is: ${data.data}');
  });
```

Basically you need to use the `onData` for onMessage or foreground or background.

Comment: Thank for reply, but it still log `broadcast received for message...`

Comment: Add it also to foreground message, and make sure you are actually sending data. Its a `Map` object.

Comment: May I ask which firebase_messaging ^version you are used? There have some bug with the latest version. except for that, your snipped work perfectly.

Comment: `firebase_messaging: ^10.0.3`
`firebase_messaging_web: ^2.0.2`